# Display 2 columns from one table having max count in column 3 and display computed sum of values from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a customer table and purchases table,
need to show cname, cid with max(customer_visits) from customer table
and sum of total_purchases by customer in purchases table.
I'm doing something like this

```
select p.cid, c.cname, sum(p.total_price)
from customers c where exists
(select max(visits_made) from customers having visits_made=max(visits_made)
and cid=p.cid)
inner join purchases p on p.cid=c.cid
group by p.cid,c.cname
```

and

```
select p.cid, c.cname, sum(p.total_price)
(select max(visits_made) from customers c where c.cid=p.cid) 
from purchases p
inner join customers c on c.cid=p.cid
group by p.cid,c.cname
```

What's going wrong with these queries?

Found the solution, had to include where clause after inner join :D

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just an aggregation query:

```
select p.cid, c.cname, sum(p.total_price) as total_price,
       max(visits_made) as visits_made
from purchases p inner join
     customers c
     on c.cid = p.cid
group by p.cid, c.cname;
```

Comment: I need to display only those tuples with max(visits_made) and don't need to show the visits_made column

Comment: Thanks man, found the solution, had to include where clause after inner join :D